# Can pure functions mutate other properties inside it's container class using `this`?

Tags: javascript, class, functional-programming, pure-function

I know that pure functions shouldn't mutate state that's not passed in as a parameter but I don't know if the `this` keyword is an exception to that rule.  Here is a simple example of what I'm thinking:

```
 class Car {
    color: string = 'red';
    make: string = 'Dodge';

    constructor() {}

    changeMake(newMake: string): string {
      this.color = 'blue';  // <-- Is this impure?
      return newMake;
    }
  }
```

Is this impure?  Why, or why not?

Comment: Aren't pure components functions? If you have `this`, that's the holder of state

Comment: Pure functions shouldn't mutate anything _at all_, save perhaps local variables that go out of scope anyways when the function is finished.

Comment: it's impure because it has a different effect when `this` refers to different values

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot mutate properties since that changes the value (object) and that is a side effect. Pure methods can expose their data, but never change them. They can create new objects and then they are considered pure:

```
class Car {
    color: string;
    make: string;

    constructor(color = 'red', make = 'Dodge') {
        this.color = color; 
        this.make = make;
    }

    changeMake(newMake: string): Car {
        return new Car(this.color, newMake);
    }
}
```

This creates a copy of the original car with the new make and thus every place the old object was used still has the old object.

A really good example of this is the Java String class, which is purely functional. Every method that returns a String that is different always return a newly constructed one.  Quite a feat when thinking it was conceived  in the golden age of OO.

Comment: javascript strings are immutable too

Comment: Two additions: A language with reference values like JS `Object`s cannot be technically pure because it has referential identity instead of the required transparency. And when you work with `class`es and their hierarchies it is only natural to work with mutations as well, because such a design relies on mutations.